# How to removeEventListener on a callback with .bind(this) attached

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

If I do:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.foo);
```

and then inside function `this.foo`  then remove it with:

```
document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.foo);
```

then it works.

However if I do:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.foo.bind(this));
```

then the function is not removed.

Is there anything I can do? I must have the correct context inside foo.

Comment: You must store a reference to the function returned by `this.foo.bind(this)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.foo.bind(this)` is returning a function which is different than the function `this.foo`. So, what you need do is keep reference to the function returned by bind

```
var handler = this.foo.bind(this);

document.addEventListener("mousedown", handler);

document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handler);
```